# Change External Variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, variables, global-variables, global

I have 1 external JS file and 2 HTML files.

I want to change the values of some variables in my JS file using HTML file # 1 and have the new values be accessible to the other HTML file.

How would I do so?

My JS File:

(buttons.js)

[image: Here are the variables whose values I want to change]

HTML #1: (Output: fifc = 4895239)

[image]

HTML #2: (Output: fifc = 0)

[image]

HTML #2 does not output the new value, rather it outputs the original value that it was set to in buttons.JS (0)

Is there some way to change fifc so that HTML #2 sees it as 4895239?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

Having an HTML file means a page load and JS variables are bound to the page that's showing now. So, there's no way to change those variables directly. It's like trying to change a variable inside a program on another.

Though, you can persist state across different sessions with sessionStorage or localStorage (the main difference is that localStorage persists even when the browser is closed and sessionStorage is cleared after that). For your need, I think sessionStorage might be better, but it's up to you.

You can do it like this

```js
// Replace fifc = 0 with this
// it basically sets the item on sessionStorage if it
// doesn't already exist
if (!sessionStorage.getItem('fifc')) {
  sessionStorage.setItem('fifc', 0),
}
```

And then, on every page, you can access the value with

```js
sessionStorage.getItem('fifc');
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot! Where would I do sessionStorage.setItem()? In my JS file or HTML 1?

Comment: I tried using it but it gives me null as the value for fifc now

Comment: You use `sessionStorage.setItem` every time you need to set a value to your "persistent variable".

Comment: The variable `fifc` doesn't mean anything anymore, your data is persisted through `sessionStorage`. If you're getting `null` from `sessionStorage.getItem`, it's because the item is not set yet. Check if you set it correctly and double check your spelling.

Comment: Just got it, thanks a lot!